# Julia unexpacted behavior: function definition inside if elseif end fails or returns wrong result

Tags: julia

I have several functions calculation the same thing using different methods. I now wanted to bundle them in one main function with a keyword argument for choosing the method. The structure I came up with looks sth. like the minimal example below. The idea behind this was to assign a specific function to a general function name, as it is used several times inside the function and I didn't want to have the if else .. structure in more than one place.

```
function testfun(input::Real; method::String = "a")
    if method == "a"
        println("Method a was chosen")
        calculate(x) = 2x # in the real code methods are assigned here, but the errors are the same
    elseif method == "b"
        println("Method b was chosen")
        calculate(x) = 3x
    else
        throw(DomainError(method))
    end
    return calculate(input)
end
```

But this code works not as expected and generates this:

```
testfun(1) # -> 3, but expected 2
testfun(1, method = "a") # -> 3, but expected 2
testfun(1, method = "b") # -> ERROR: UndefVarError: calculate not defined, but expected 3
testfun(1, method = "c") #  throws the correct DomainError
```

What am I missing here that explains this behavior, as the println() triggers correctly? Julia version was 1.5.
What is the correct/ best way to build this type of function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a function inside a function depending on variable values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982259/how-to-define-a-function-inside-a-function-depending-on-variable-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I paste this straight into the REPL, I get this: `WARNING: Method definition calculate(Any) in module Main at REPL[35]:4 overwritten at REPL[35]:7.` Looks like for some reason only the last definition of `calculate` will be used.

You can use an anonymous function like `calculate = x -> 2x`:

```
function testfun(input::Real; method::String = "a")
    if method == "a"
        println("Method a was chosen")
        calculate = x -> 2x # in the real code methods are assigned here, but the errors are the same
    elseif method == "b"
        println("Method b was chosen")
        calculate = x -> 3x
    else
        throw(DomainError(method))
    end
    return calculate(input)
end
```

Output:

```
julia> testfun(1)
Method a was chosen
2

julia> testfun(1; method="b")
Method b was chosen
3
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602. In Julia 1.6 and above this gives the warning you mention.

Comment: @fredrikekre, so it's being promoted to an error now - much better than a warning

Comment: No it is a warning.

Comment: @fredrikekre, someone wrote a [pull request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/39498) to make this an error. However, there doesn't seem to be a consensus yet...

Comment: Yes I know, but that will not go into Julia 1.6 in any case, so for now it is a warning.

Comment: Interesting that haven't seen the Warning in all my testing ... but I will embrace anonymous functions more from now on, thanks!
@fredrikekre Thanks for the reference to the GitHub issue, this makes it more clear what is the actual underlying problem!